# Can I check a suspect .zip file without downloading it?

Tags: email, download, testing

I am using Linux Fedora 20 and BT Yahoo mail. I have received an email with an attached .zip file, but I suspect that it might be malicious and dangerous even to download the attachment -- it might not even be a genuine zipped file.

I am afraid that simply downloading it might also do something detrimental to my computer.

Is there any way of checking this file without actually downloading it to my computer?

Comment: "look at the file contents before downloading" is a logical impossibility.

Comment: It is logically possible that there might be software that will check the format of a file without actually storing it on the file i system on my computer.

Comment: It might be a ZIP bomb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb), but just downloading it won't trigger it. If it's malware it's most likely aimed at Windows computers. Of course, if you suspect it to be malicious the best thing is to delete the mail altogether, or ask the sender.

Comment: Of course that's right, @HarryWeston, but you didn't say "storing it on the file i system on my computer" in your question, you said "downloading it".

Answer (score 3):

Is impossible, but most web mail services (yahoo, gmail, etc) check the file for virus before downloading, also you can use a third tools to check if the file is dangerous or not, for example you can forward the mail to scan@virustotal.com